# Delphi: getting access violation error at run-time

Tags: delphi, access-violation

I'm pretty new to Delphi and am attempting to use different units to store TLists and TObjects, as well as generate other combobox options based on previous combobox selections. I am receiving the following error messages immediately after running:

> Project Project1.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message
> 'access violation at  0x004087d7: read of address 0x00000000
>
> Access violation at address 00408813 in module 'Project1.exe'. Read of
> address 00000000.

I've traced through the steps in the debugging tool but I can't see why it won't work. I have googled the issue and have found a few solutions but nothing that seems like it applies to my current problem.

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TfMain = class(TForm)
    lCPU: TLabel;
    cbCPU: TComboBox;
    lGPU: TLabel;
    cbGPU: TComboBox;
    lMotherboard: TLabel;
    cbMotherboard: TComboBox;
    lRAM: TLabel;
    cbRAM: TComboBox;
    eCompatible: TEdit;
    lCompatible: TLabel;
    eCost: TEdit;
    lCost: TLabel;
    Label11: TLabel;
    lbCPU: TListBox;
    lbMotherboard: TListBox;
    lbGPU: TListBox;
    lbRAM: TListBox;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure cbCPUChange(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
//    procedure cbCPUpopulate();
  end;

  type TGPU = class(TObject)
    public
      name : string;
      vram : integer;
      clock : integer;
      price : string;
  end;

  type TCPU = class(TObject)
    public
      name : string;
      cores : integer;
      clock : real;
      intel : boolean;
      amd : boolean;
      price : string;
  end;

  type TMobo = class(TObject)
    public
      name : string;
      intel : boolean;
      amd : boolean;
      price : string;
  end;

  type TRAM = class(TObject)
    public
      name : string;
      memory : integer;
      clock : integer;
      price : string;
  end;

var
  fMain: TfMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses CPUs, GPUs, Motherboards;

procedure TfMain.cbCPUChange(Sender: TObject);
var
i : integer;
mobo : TMobo;
begin
  if TCPU(fMain.cbCPU.ItemIndex).intel = true then begin
    for i := 0 to Motherboards.MoboPartsList.Count-1 do begin
      mobo := TMobo(Motherboards.MoboPartsList.Items[i]);
      if mobo.intel = true then begin
        fMain.cbMotherboard.Items.AddObject(mobo.name, mobo);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure cbCPUpopulate();
var
i : integer;
CPU : TCPU;
begin
  for i := 0 to CPUs.CPUPartsList.Count-1 do begin
    CPU := TCPU(CPUs.CPUPartsList.Items[i]);
    fMain.cbCPU.Items.AddObject(CPU.name, CPU);
  end;
end;

procedure TfMain.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Motherboards.MakeMoboList;
  CPUs.MakeCPUList();
  GPUs.popgpulist();
  cbCPUpopulate;
end;

end.
```

Comment: The AV is telling you that a `nil` pointer is being accessed, and giving you the exact memory address of the code that is trying to access it. Didn't you try having the debugger go to that memory address so you can see the exact code that is failing?

Comment: That's not an *error while attempting to compile*. It's a runtime error, which can only happen once you've successfully compiled and linked your executable and then run that executable. An *error while attempting to compile* would prevent you from creating an application that can be run to produce that access violation.

Answer (score 5):

In `cbCPUChange()`, you are accessing the `TCPU` objects incorrectly.

The expression `TCPU(fMain.cbCPU.ItemIndex)` is type-casting a **list index** into an **object pointer**.  You need to instead use the `ItemIndex` to access the ComboBox's `Objects[]` property, which is filled with `TCPU` objects by `cbCPUpopulate()`.

Also, there is no need to use the `fMain` global variable from inside a method of the `TfMain` class.  Use the method's implicit `Self` pointer instead.

Try something more like this:

```pascal
procedure TfMain.cbCPUChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;
  mobo : TMobo;
begin
  cbMotherboard.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    cbMotherboard.Items.Clear;
    i := cbCPU.ItemIndex;
    if i < 0 then Exit;
    if TCPU(cbCPU.Items.Objects[i]).intel then begin
      for i := 0 to Motherboards.MoboPartsList.Count-1 do begin
        mobo := TMobo(Motherboards.MoboPartsList.Items[i]);
        if mobo.intel then begin
          cbMotherboard.Items.AddObject(mobo.name, mobo);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    cbMotherboard.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

---

On a side note, the declarations of the `TCPU`, `TMobo`, and `TRAM` types do not belong in the `MainForm` unit.  They should be declared in the other units that are actually creating object lists of those types, eg: `TCPU` in the `CPUs` unit, `TMobo` in the `Motherboards` unit, etc:

```pascal
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TfMain = class(TForm)
    lCPU: TLabel;
    cbCPU: TComboBox;
    lGPU: TLabel;
    cbGPU: TComboBox;
    lMotherboard: TLabel;
    cbMotherboard: TComboBox;
    lRAM: TLabel;
    cbRAM: TComboBox;
    eCompatible: TEdit;
    lCompatible: TLabel;
    eCost: TEdit;
    lCost: TLabel;
    Label11: TLabel;
    lbCPU: TListBox;
    lbMotherboard: TListBox;
    lbGPU: TListBox;
    lbRAM: TListBox;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure cbCPUChange(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure cbCPUpopulate;
  public
  end;

var
  fMain: TfMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  CPUs, GPUs, Motherboards;

procedure TfMain.cbCPUChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;
  mobo : Motherboards.TMobo;
begin
  cbMotherboard.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    cbMotherboard.Items.Clear;
    i := cbCPU.ItemIndex;
    if i < 0 then Exit;
    if CPUs.TCPU(cbCPU.Items.Objects[i]).intel then begin
      for i := 0 to Motherboards.MoboPartsList.Count-1 do begin
        mobo := Motherboards.TMobo(Motherboards.MoboPartsList.Items[i]);
        if mobo.intel then begin
          cbMotherboard.Items.AddObject(mobo.name, mobo);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    cbMotherboard.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TfMain.cbCPUpopulate;
var
  i : integer;
  CPU : CPUs.TCPU;
begin
  for i := 0 to CPUs.CPUPartsList.Count-1 do begin
    CPU := CPUs.TCPU(CPUs.CPUPartsList.Items[i]);
    cbCPU.Items.AddObject(CPU.name, CPU);
  end;
end;

procedure TfMain.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Motherboards.MakeMoboList;
  CPUs.MakeCPUList;
  GPUs.popgpulist;
  cbCPUpopulate;
end;

end.
```